# f is a linear map from $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ to $M_k(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and $M_k(\mathbb{F})$ are matrix spaces and their oders indicated by their subscripts.

let $f$
a linear map from $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ to $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ such
that $\forall A,B$ in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ satisfying that $$f(AB)=f(A)f(B) $$ $$ f(I_n)=I_k $$ $I_n$ and $I_k$ are identity matrix in their own filds.

Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $f(A)$ then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of matrix $A$.

I have tried independently. I want to write down my train of thought on this problem, but It is hard for me to express, because I don't know much terms in mathematical due to my non-English native speaker identity, I request your pardon.

Comment: Questions without "context" are usually bad received. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).
 Can't you [type formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)? and use a translator online?

Comment: Does this (mutatis mutandis) answer your question? [\*-homomorphisms $M_m(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371021/homomorphisms-m-m-mathbbc-rightarrow-m-n-mathbbc)

Comment: Online translator may work well in translating daily conversation, but it is not work well with professioanl fields such as mathematics, I don't use translator for the fear of mistranslation.

Comment: I agree. Then, what you could do is put your original text (in your native language, and with formulas when necessary), followed by an automatic translation (or semi-automatic: corrected by yourself when needed). And what about the linked post?